# How to minimize a function?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

[image]

I'm currently doing the following:

- Express $x_3$ from the constraint
- Plug into the objective function
- I now have a function with two variables which should be easier to minimize

The problem is that I don't know how to proceed further. What must I do to minimize the new function and how is its minimum related to the minimum of the original function?

Comment: Set the partial derivatives to zero, solve the system, you get a set of stationary points. The character of each point is determined by the second partials.

Comment: This is a course on optimization. The textbook mentions two approaches: reducing the function and finding critical points with derivatives, or finding the gradient and hessian matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the gradient of the function is equal to zero in such points. Then you can compute the Hessian and evaluate it at the three points to determine the answers to question ii).

Comment: Check the gradient with which points? The ones given, I assume?

Comment: Yes, you compute the partial derivatives of your function with respect the 2 variables, then substitute the points you have.\

Comment: So if I plug the point into the gradient and I don't get a (0, 0, 0), then it is not a stationary point? Just asking to be sure.

Comment: That's correct. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_point#Classification

Comment: Hmmm I calculated the gradient real quick and it turns out none of the given points result in a (0, 0, 0) point when plugged in it. Does that make the second question redundant (as none of the points appear to be critical, they can't be min/max/inflection)?

Comment: Notice that only the second and third point satisfy the constraint of the problem. So I suggest you to compute the gradient and the Hessian for the function in the three variables (without removing one of them), and then plug in the two points.

Comment: $(1,0,1)$ is a saddle point. Further, the question ii) asks for each stationary point (given the constraint), not those points. You have to do what I said: set the partial derivatives to zero (or, equivalently, ser the gradient to zero) and solve the system of equations. Then plug these points into the hessian.

Comment: @RafaBudría All of the first partial derivatives end up being non-linear. That would complicate the system.

Comment: Yes, they do, but in the previsible 3rd or 4th degree equation we know a root from the point i). Maybe it is easier using the Lagrange multipliers method.

Comment: @RafaBudría Solved it and got the proof that (1,0,1) is a saddle point. Thanks for the help!